# Merge Multiple Objects from Fetch request

Tags: javascript

I'm trying trying to merge multiple objects that come from an API and group them by their id and values but any changes will only apply to the single object as opposed to all of them.

My latest attempt:

```
let carIds = [7, 78, 34, 59];

let url = "";
carIds.map(id => {
  url = `https://example.com/api/reports?carId=${id}`;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => carData(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

const carData = data => {
  const reports = data.cars[0].car.car_makes;

  let result = reports.reduce(function(r, a) {
    r[a.car_make_id] = r[a.car_make_id] || [];
    r[a.car_make_id].push(a.car_model);
    return r;
  }, {});
};
```

The results I get from the API is similar to this (no commas included in the API response):

```
{"id":1,"car_make":[{"car_make_id":"7","model_year":2000,"car_model":"Viper"}]}
{"id":2,"car_make":[{"car_make_id":"7","model_year":1997,"car_model":"Elantra"}]}
{"id":3,"car_make":[{"car_make_id":"7","model_year":2011,"car_model":"Yukon"}]}
{"id":4,"car_make":[{"car_make_id":"7","model_year":1996,"car_model":"Suburban 2500"}]}
{"id":5,"car_make":[{"car_make_id":"7","model_year":1995,"car_model":"G-Series G10"}]}
```

Where the car_make_id are the same but the car_model are different.

The expected output should be:

```
{
  car_make_id: 7,
  values: ['Viper', 'Elantra', 'Yukon', etc...]
}
```

But the actual output is:

```
{
  7: ['Viper']
}
{
  7: ['Elantra']
}
{
  7: ['Yukon']
}
{
  7: ['Suburban 2500']
}
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to use `Promise.all()` to wait for all results to have come in before processing and merging them.

Comment: The actual output cannot be that, can it? I don't think javascript would allow you to have an object with multiple of the same keys...

Comment: You have multiple parallel asynchronous fetch requests running, so you'll probably want to use `Promise.all` (and properly use `map()`) to turn the array of carIds into an array of API responses, and only then reduce it

Comment: Hey @TKoL, you're right. I corrected the actual output.

Comment: Hey @AKX, thanks for the suggestions and edits. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Hey @ChrisG, can you elaborate on the "properly use map()"?

Comment: `map()`, as opposed to `forEach()`, returns a new array built from whatever the callback returns. So the idea is to return the `fetch(url).then(r => r.json())` inside the callback, which will amount to an array of Promises. This can be passed to `Promise.all()` and the result `then()`ed to get the array of API results. [Like this.](https://pastebin.com/tLW69Cis)

Comment: Hey @ChrisG, that was very helpful. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work:

```js
let result = reports.reduce(function(r, a) {
    if(r["car_make_id"] != a.car_make_id){
      r["car_make_id"] = a.car_make_id;
      r["values"] = [];
    }
    r["values"].push(a.car_model);
    return r;
  }, {});
```